# DolphinDB: the data deduplication effect of using upsert! in a TSDB database

Tags: duplicates, time-series, dolphindb

I have learned that the `upsert!` function performs data deduplication based on its parameter *keyColNames*, while the TSDB engine deals with duplicated records based on the sort columns of a table.

If I use `upsert!` to update a TSDB database, what would happen if the columns specified by the parameter *keyColNames *and the sort columns of the table are not consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `upsert!` in a TSDB database, the parameter *keyColNames* must include all the specified sort columns. Therefore, duplicated records are managed based on the sort columns.